# Change style of a specific text inside a input text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, input

I want to apply some style to a specific text inside an input text tag

If the user introduces "Hello world" in the input text tag and the special text is "world"

I hope this Output:

[image]

My html code looks like this

```
<input name="inputTest" ng-model="inputTest">
```

My javascript code is activated by an external button that call a "checkInput" function

```
let specialText = "world"
textArr = inputTest.split(/(\s+)/);
for(const text of textArr){
   if(text == specialText){
      //Do something to change style of the "special text"
   }
}
```

Comment: You should include some code with what you tried so far, so that people can take a closer look at your approach and guide you to the solution.

Comment: You may need to look at a contenteditable div instead, or make the actual input opacity 0 and show the text (plus styling) that you want on top. Give it a go and put your code into your question - it makes it very much easier to give a relevant and accurate answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've tried nonsense things like replace the world "world" to "<b>world</b>" but obviusly it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can be done with an input element.
One option to consider is using editable content.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content
Which you can style more freely than an actual input.
You could also use javascript in combination with editable content to handle the styling.

Comment: I'll try to do it with editablecontent

Answer (score 1):

One rough approach you can try like:

In your class file:

```
inputText: string;
specialText: string;

onTextInput(text: string): void {
   const inputValues = text.split(' ');
   this.inputText = inputValues[0]; // Hello
   this.specialText = inputValues[1]; // World
}
```

In the template file:

```
<input type="text" #specialInput (keydown)="onTextInput(specialInput.value)" />
<p>{{inputText}} <strong>{{specialText}}</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use syntax highlight lib's like
highlight.js

and define new syntax and load it to work as realtime input

an example of highlight.js language definition is here :
https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language-guide.html